# Pandas DataFrame dtype switches when row is inserted using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

**Aim**
I am trying to append a row to a pandas data frame with replacement, where maintaining data type (dtype) is crucial.

**Question**
Why, when inserting `row` into `data_frame`, does the dtype switch to `object`, while neither object is of this dtype, and this dtype could not be inferred from the data?

**Data**
Both `row` and `data_frame` are `pd.DataFrame` objects with the same columns, of the same dtypes.
`data_frame` contains many rows with unique indices.
`row` only contains a single entry with a unique index.

**Issue**
To prevent duplication of indices I would like to use `.loc` as follows:

```
data_frame.loc[idx] = row.loc[idx]
```

However, this changes the dtype of the entire data frame to `object`:

```
>>> data_frame['column'].dtype 
Int64Dtype()
>>> row['column'].dtype
Int64Dtype()
>>> data_frame.loc[idx] = row.loc[idx]
>>> data_frame['column'].dtype 
dtype('O')
```

**Alternative**

I've since chosen to work with the following alternative, which effectively does the same thing by requires to check and drop duplicates instead of immediately overwriting them:

```
data_frame = pd.concat([data_frame, row])
data_frame = data_frame[~data_frame.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

**PS**
I have read documentation on `.loc` but I cannot find details on how dtypes are handled. I had presumed that the dtype of the master data frame would be maintained.
I used to work with row as a `pd.Series` object, but I was not able to properly set the dtype here.

Comment: generally, when you slice a single row `data_frame.loc[idx]` you would get a series of dtype `Object`, so `data_frame.loc[idx] = row.loc[idx]` inserts/updates a row with `Object` dtype, and hence all the cells in that row is treated as an object, which then converts the columns into Object dtype as well. It is not a bug, but rather a inheritance weakness of Pandas design.  On the other hand, it would be fine if you do `data_frame.loc[[idx]] = row`, or `data_frame.update(row)`.

Comment: On a second read, `df.loc[x]` should **never** be used to insert data. Pandas is designed as column-based.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a known bug since 2014:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6485

The bug is caused because enlargment is done in 2 stages, and a `nan` is placed in that column first, then its assigned.

It is advised to avoid this by not assigning with enlargement.
Options are populating the dataframe on construction, or using `concat`.